# BeautifulSoup couldn't find everything

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data out of a web page, the data that I want to scrape is set like this:

```
<div id="pagetitle">
      <a href="some_link">some_text</a>
      "some_text2"
      <a href="some_link2">some_text3</a>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to get `some_text3` I'm trying with this code

```
soup = soup(page, "html5lib")

author = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'pagetitle'}).a.string

print(author)
```

when I do this I only get `some_text` I also tried with:

```
author = soup.find_all('a', {'id' : 'pagetitle'})
```

but I get an empty list, I also tried it with:

```
author = soup.find(id='pagetitle').prettify()
```

and I get the whole code but I don't know how to get only `some_text3`
I also tried to use different parsers but none of them worked
also sorry if this is hard to understand but It's my second question here, I would kindly accept all recommendations if there are.

Comment: Are you sure you get the HTML you *think* you get from the response?

Comment: Be careful assigning `soup = soup(page, "html5lib")` as you may lose reference to `bs4`. Choose a different name for your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector with `:nth-last-child()`. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<div id="pagetitle">
      <a href="some_link">some_text</a>
      "some_text2"
      <a href="some_link2">some_text3</a>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

txt = soup.select_one("#pagetitle > a:nth-last-child(1)").text
print(txt)
```

Prints:

```
some_text3
```

---

Or: use `[-1]` to get last element:

```
txt = soup.select("#pagetitle a")[-1].text
print(txt)
```